# How to show alert box after successful or not data deletion in mssql

Tags: javascript, php, sql, sql-server

I want to show JavaScript alert after successful or not data deletion in MSSQL. How to do this? I have written this code but it shows only the `message=success` part alert everytime, even when the deletion dont work becasue of errors like "conflict with reference(foreign_key)" So when i click on this link.

```
 echo "<a class='activater'  href='ma_QualiOverviewloeschen.php?TestaufstellungID=".$row['TestaufstellungID'] ."&QualiID=".$row['QualiID'] ."' title='Qualitest l&ouml;schen' data-toggle='tooltip' onclick='confirm_delete()'>   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
```

It calls the following php Page, which handle the SQL Part:

```
$QualiDelete =("DELETE FROM MyDB.dbo.Testaufstellung WHERE MyDB.dbo.Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID = :TestaufstellungID");
$QualiDelete .=("DELETE FROM MyDB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben WHERE MyDB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID = :QualiID");

$sth = $connection->prepare($QualiDelete);
$sth->execute(array(':TestaufstellungID' => $TestaufstellungID, ':QualiID:' => $QualiID));

                if($sth)
                {
                    header("location: ma_QualiOverview.php?message=success");   
                }
                else
                {
                    echo sqlsrv_errors();
                    header("location: ma_QualiOverview.php?message=failed");    
                }
                $connection = null;
```

Back to the main page where the link is clicked the following `ifelse`consider on `message`should Show me the right alert.

```
<?php
if($_GET['message']=='success'){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Erfolgreich gelöscht.");';
    echo '</script>';
} elseif($_GET['message']=='failed'){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Nicht gelöscht, da Quali "ongoing" ist.");';
    echo '</script>';
}
?>
```

What do i miss?

Comment: I doubt your query even work. The give string, once concat, will provide a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sth` will never be `falsy`, you have to check the return value of `$sth->execute`
Also, you should echo the errors after sending out the header.

Since `$sth` is always defined, you always get the success result
See the modified code here

```
$QualiDelete =("DELETE FROM MyDB.dbo.Testaufstellung WHERE MyDB.dbo.Testaufstellung.TestaufstellungID = :TestaufstellungID");
$QualiDelete .=("DELETE FROM MyDB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben WHERE MyDB.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben.QualiID = :QualiID");

$sth = $connection->prepare($QualiDelete);//Check the value returned instead of $sth
$result = $sth->execute(array(':TestaufstellungID' => $TestaufstellungID, ':QualiID:' => $QualiID));

                if($result )
                {
                    header("location: ma_QualiOverview.php?message=success");   
                }
                else
                {
                    header("location: ma_QualiOverview.php?message=failed");  
                    echo sqlsrv_errors();//Echo must be after header

                }
                $connection = null;
```